# React subcomponent doesn't re-render when array prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the main app with two subcomponents, both receiving the same `model` property.

The first subcomponent handles a number prop from `model.myNumberProperty` and the second subcomponent handles an array prop from `model.myArrayProperty`

Changing the `model.myNumberProperty` in subcomponent one triggers a re-render but
changing the `model.myArrayProperty` in subcomponent two doesn't

```
function App() {
  const model = MyModel();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Main app
      <ComponentOne dataObject={model} />
      <ComponentTwo dataObject={model} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function MyModel() {
  let _propOne = 0;
  let _propTwo = ["one"];

  const propOne = () => {
    return _propOne;
  };
  const propTwo = () => {
    return _propTwo;
  };

  const modifyPropOne = () => {
    _propOne++;
    console.log("modifying prop one", _propOne);
  };

  const modifyPropTwo = () => {
    _propTwo.push("new element");
  };

  return Object.freeze({ propOne, propTwo, modifyPropOne, modifyPropTwo });
}


const ComponentOne = props => {
  const [propOne, setPropOne] = useState(props.dataObject.propOne());

  const onButtonOneClick = () => {
    props.dataObject.modifyPropOne();
    setPropOne(props.dataObject.propOne());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello ComponentOne:</p>

      <button onClick={onButtonOneClick}>ModifyPropOne</button>
      <p>{propOne}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentTwo = props => {
  const [propTwo, setPropTwo] = useState(props.dataObject.propTwo());

  const onButtonTwoClick = () => {
    props.dataObject.modifyPropTwo();
    setPropTwo([...props.dataObject.propTwo()]);
    console.log('Prop two', props.dataObject.propTwo());
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello ComponentTwo</p>

      <button onClick={onButtonTwoClick}>ModifyPropTwo</button>
      {propTwo.map((value, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{value}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Please look at [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/updatearrayprop-v60bz) to test the case.

I am using React Hooks.
The solution to my problem should be React only, so no Redux or other 3rd party libs.

Please note that my model is a freezed object to enforce encapsulation so I can not just recreate the whole object. The model in the example is a reduced and simplified one, In my real project, it is a complex Card game object which handles lots of arrays.

Comment: Next time please add all necessary code in the question in addition to the sandbox, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On calling `setState`, React makes [shallow comparison](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) with the previous state and decides if the render phase should proceed.

In your case, it has the same reference, therefore no render triggered.

To fix it, set a copy of your array as the new state.

```
const onButtonTwoClick = () => {
  props.dataObject.modifyPropTwo();
  //                v Make a new copy.
  setPropTwo([...props.dataObject.propTwo()]);
};
```

Refer to [The power of not mutating Data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).

[image: Edit updateArrayProp]

Comment: life can be simple :)